# Power of a runner

Tags: power

How can someone calculate the power in watt that a runner produces, when he runs uphill and downhill?

Is there any algorithm? It is important to take under consideration the uphill and downhill elements of the run.

---

Thank you for your answers but i am confused since i don't have a background in physics.
To make thinks simple, i have some values, and using these values and maybe some constants like gravity, i want to create a calculator for real time watt production.
These values are:

INSTANT VALUES: speed, distance, hr, kcal, ascent, descent, duration.
OTHER VALUES: body mass, vertical speed (average), ascent time, descent time, max hr, rest hr, vo2max.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5882/convert-running-speed-uphill-to-equivilent-speed-on-flat

Comment: This is in fact fully answered by the answers on 5882, but I'm a little hesitant to close this as a duplicate. Opinions are solicited from passers by.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the runner's velocity $v$ is constant, his kinetic energy $\frac{1}{2} m v^2$ will be constant, so all we have to do is worry about his potential energy $U=mgh$. Power is rate of change in energy, so we take $P=\frac{dU}{dt}=m g \frac{dh}{dt}$. That's the power he outputs. If he weighs 70kg, and goes up a hill at 1 meter per second (So... that might be similar to sprinting up stairs?) Then we have $P=70 * 9.8 * 1 \text{kg} \frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}^2} \frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}=686 \frac{\text{J}}{\text{s}}$

Note that if $\frac{dh}{dt}$ is negative, $P$ will be negative. It's also important to note that it's important that we took the runner's kinetic energy to be constant. If we had $E=U+\text{Ke}$, $\frac{dE}{dT}=\frac{dU}{dt}+\frac{d\text{Ke}}{dt}$, but since $\frac{d\text{Ke}}{dt}$ is zero we can ignore it.

This assumes simplifications like no friction, no heat generation, etc., in order to reduce it to a simple kinematics problem.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not easy as it involves a complex system as a human body.
There is no algorithm as far as I know. It depends on what level of correctness you need.

First, you'll have to take into account the mechanical work. This is always $mgh$ where $m$ is the man's mass, $g$ is gravity acceleration, $h$ is the difference in height (can be negative).

The problem is that a runner will spend energy even when running on a flat surface (this doesn't happen in the ideal case). For this I'll suggest to take into account: 1. the heat: the runner warms up and dissipates energy; 2. the friction.
I think they are very difficult to estimate, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to find estimates of the amount of energy you use for running, on training-sites etc. The figure is given as a power as well (J/s). Then you just need to figure out the power used for running uphill. That is explained well by neurofuzzy.

That should give you a decent estimate.