# How does a treadmill incline mechanism work?

Tags: classical-mechanics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between running up a hill and running up an inclined treadmill?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/whats-the-difference-between-running-up-a-hill-and-running-up-an-inclined-tread)

I want to know how a system can give so many small steps of inclination and so strong to against impact from people running. Thanks

Comment: Related to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1639/

Comment: a hydraulic piston fixed to 'mill' and base could be used to easily vary inclination.

Comment: A lead screw and gear box is probably cheaper and easier than hydraulics

Comment: I really don't understand why this mechanical mechanism question would relate to people run on a treadmill.

Comment: @Nic Thanks for your suggestion, but do you think a treadmill would have a hydraulic position system inside?

Comment: see http://www.google.com.ar/patents/US5591106 for description of one possible mechanism.

Comment: IMO the duplicate given has absolutely nothing to do with the question asked. It is about mechanisms for providing an incline mechanism. It might be considered an "engineering" question - but it's definitely not a duplicate of the one marked.